# when click on specific radio button the text should appear jst below of that Radio Button How to do that

Tags: android, radio-button

I'm trying to create a horizontal list of radio buttons where the text
to each button is below the button and not to the right of it as
default.

I'm able to create the following:
( O is the radio button and xx is the text to each button)

O xx O xx O xx

But I want to have this:  the text should appear when i click on particular radio button otherwise it should be invisible....

O O O
xx xx xx

Please provide sample code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
    final RadioButton r = new RadioButton(this);
    r.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1)
        {
            if(r.isChecked())
                r.setText("xyx");
            else
                r.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: no i got the solution i made the toast message for specific duration so that user can see that message and he can select if he want to... and how thanks for your considered reply..

Answer (score 0):

You could use radio button labels (and arrange via table, etc).

Ie:

```
<table>
<tr><td> radio1 </td><td> radio2 </td><td> radio3 </td><td> <label for="radio1">xx</label> </td><td> <label for="radio2">xx</label> </td><td> <label for="radio3">xx</label> </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think the person has asked about the android code not the html one.

Comment: Oops, sorry jumped the gun on that one.  Could re-write your application in HTML5 though... :)

Comment: I'm actually curious on this one myself now, I'll have to check in later to see if it gets resolved!